# Showing $trace\left(\sum_{i=1}^j u_i u_i^T D\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^j \lambda_i$, where $u_i$ orthonormal & $D$ a diag. matrix w/ $\lambda_i$ entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose $\{u_i:1 \leq i \leq j\}$ are a set of orthonormal vectors,  and $D$ is a diagonal marix such that $D = diag(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_p)$, arranged so that $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_p >0$. Then, I would like to show that:

$$
trace\left(\sum_{i=1}^j u_i u_i^T D\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^j \lambda_i
$$

My approach is to do the following:

\begin{align*}
trace\left(\sum_{i=1}^j u_i u_i^T D\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^j \sum_{l=1}^p u_{il}^2 \lambda_l \\
&= \sum_{l=1}^p u_{1l}^2 \lambda_l + \sum_{l=1}^p u_{2l}^2 \lambda_l + \ldots + \sum_{l=1}^p u_{jl}^2 \lambda_l \\
& \leq \lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_j
\end{align*}

However, I cannot figure out how the last step follows. I understand we have that:

$$
\sum_{l=1}^p u_{1l}^2 = \sum_{l=1}^p u_{2l}^2 = \ldots = \sum_{l=1}^p u_{jl}^2 = 1
$$

But I don't see how this allows us to get the last inequality. In particular, it seems that we are just concentrating all the weighting to $u_{11}^2 = u_{22}^2 = \ldots = u_{jj}^2 = 1$ for each term.

**Finally**, if the last inequality holds, would it hold for any arbitrary reordering of the indices?

Comment: In order for this to be true, we need an assumption such as $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_p$

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it!

Comment: We can obtain the result using the [Von Neumann trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities#Von_Neumann.27s_trace_inequality), but perhaps that's a bit much

Comment: Indeed, that last step is the tricky bit.  I agree that it is not clear, a priori, that we should concentrate the weights as you describe.  Some tricky optimization needs to be done at some point.  To me, this problem has the flavor of the Eckhart Young theorem.

Comment: We can also get a proof using the [Weyl matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory)

Comment: Let me know if you're interested in seeing either of those proofs. You haven't given much context, so I don't know how much matrix analysis I'm allowed to assume.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, am I right to say that there are two constraints going on? The first being the decreasing order of the $\lambda_i$'s, and the second being that the sets of vectors $u_{1l}^2, u_{2l}^2, \ldots,  u_{jl}^2$ (when $l$ is taken from $1$ to $p$ for each and put in a row vector) must all be orthonormal to each other? I am pretty familiar with matrix analysis and would be interested in seeing either proof, thank you so much!!

Comment: I wouldn't consider the decreasing order of $\lambda_i$s a constraint in the usual sense, but I agree with the second bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_i = u_{1,i}^2 + u_{2,i}^2 + \cdots + u_{j, i}^2$ for $1 \leq i \leq p$. Exactly we want to find the maximum value of
$$
x_1\lambda_1 + x_2\lambda_2 + \cdots + x_p\lambda_p \tag{$\bigstar$}
$$
There are **at least** two constraints for $x_i$s, namely,
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_p = j \tag{$\spadesuit$}
$$
and
$$
0 \leq x_i \leq 1 \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq p \tag{$\clubsuit$}
$$
With only constraints $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$, along with the fact that $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_p > 0$, $(\bigstar)$ attains its maximum value when $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_j = 1$ and $x_{j+1} = x_{j+2} = \cdots = x_p = 0$. That is, the maximum value of $(\bigstar)$ under $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$ is $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_j$. Because we obtain this value under weaker constraints than that of the original problem, the value $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_j$ is also an upper bound for the original problem.

Comment: Fantastic! A very interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick approach: let $U$ be the matrix whose columns are $u_1,\dots,u_j$. Notably, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^j u_iu_i^TD = (UU^TD)
$$
And we note that $UU^T$ is a $p \times p$ orthogonal projection matrix, which is to say that it is orthogonally similar to
$$
\pmatrix{I_j & 0\\0& 0}
$$
Both $UU^T$ and $D$ are positive definite, so their eigenvalues are also their singular values.  In particular, $\sigma_i(D) = \lambda_i(D)$, $\sigma_i(UU^T) = 1$ for $i \leq j$ and $\sigma_i(UU^T) = 0$ for $i > j$. Applying the Von Neumann matrix inequality, we have
$$
trace\left(\sum_{i=1}^j u_i u_i^T D\right) = 
trace([UU^T]D) \leq \sum_{i=1}^p \sigma_i(UU^T)\sigma_i(D) = \sum_{i=1}^j \lambda_i
$$